# ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware is for what? how to use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The official document about `ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware` is short and direct. But it didn't tell us its specifics, also the reason why `Rails` load it in default after the decleration of its drawback of not thread safe!

Comment: Does this other question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061161/what-is-activesupportcachestrategylocalcache-used-for

More information: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Strategy/LocalCache.html

Answer (score -1):

I've answered this question in other place.

In short, `LocalCache` is a way to improve access speed and cooperate with normal cache.

[What is ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061161/what-is-activesupportcachestrategylocalcache-used-for/24999830#24999830)